# ST7735S Update memory without updating display

Tags: display

I am designing firmware for a 80 x 160 TFT display controlled by an [ST7735S](https://www.crystalfontz.com/controllers/Sitronix/ST7735S/437/) LCD controller. As expected, the screen takes about 0.25s to draw an entire frame due to the speed limitations of the SPI bus I am working with.

I would, however, prefer the redrawing to be invisible. Is there any way to update the contents of the controller's on-board memory without also updating the contents of the screen? The idea would be to show the previous frame until the new frame is fully transferred from the MCU to the ST7735S.

The only command I could find that allows data to be written to the memory, without also displaying it, blanks the screen.

Comment: What speed have you configured your SPI bus clock for? The display looks like it's capable of 15MHz, which would probably lead to a full-screen update time of about 1/10 of what you're currently seeing.

Comment: The speed of the SPI bus is currently 8MHz which is the fastest the microcontroller can manage. I am also accessing SPI memory on the same bus which adds additional delays. I am happy with the update speed in any case, I just want a more instant transition between frames.

Comment: @Pieter How are you updating the screen now? And with what? Copying from SPI Flash one byte at a time, or in blocks?

Comment: I am copying blocks of 64 bytes (cannot increase due to ram limitations) at a time from the microcontroller to the ST7735S.

Comment: The data I am transferring to the screen is stored in the program memory of the microcontroller. I also have some data stored on SPI flash.

Comment: The ST7735 only has enough memory to store a single frame of the maximum resolution it supports (132 x 162 pixels). Even though that's larger than your actual 80 x 160 display, it's not quite double the size - so there's not enough RAM to 'double-buffer' where you display from one area while you write to another. I think you're out of luck here ...

Comment: I thought as much. If I find a workaround I will update the post.